# Using Delete Button instead of Html.ActionLink to call a action of controller?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a Html.ActionLink like:

`<%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCRMRequest", new { Id = item.Id })%>`

I have a Scenario like :

[image: Scenario]

I need Delete button instead of Html.ActionLink. On click of delete I want to prompt for confirmation and if user selects yes then delete the record else not delete. I Know it can be done using javascript but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "Delete", 
    "DeleteCRMRequest", 
    new { id = item.Id }, 
    new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this article?');" }) 
%>
```